# Webdriver: Change file name before it's saved to the folder

Tags: python, webdriver, nas

When I use webdriver to browse the website, it will automatically download the file to my folder, but the file name is "Bike.gz", is it possible to change its name to "{current time}.txt" before save it to my folders? For example, as "2019-03-07-11-46.txt".

Code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {  
"download.default_directory": r"\\xxx.xx.xxx.xx\bike_test",  
"download.prompt_for_download": False,  
"download.directory_upgrade": True,   
"safebrowsing.enabled": True
}) 
driver_main = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) 
driver_main.get("http://data.xxxx/xxxx")
```

Also, "\xxx.xx.xxx.xx\bike_test" is my NAS path, if I run it on AWS, how can I download the file and save it directly to my NAS folder **bike_test**? Or do I have to save it in my AWS folder first and transform it after?

Comment: I think, WebDriver is simulate of our hand.
This means, if we can change filename with manually, then we can do in webdriver.

Or, download file with Python

Comment: @Winner if I do it manually, I cannot change the name during the process of download, which means I should probably do it after it's downloaded.

Comment: Yes, I am also waiting this answer.